# Richard Hamming's art of probability solution

Tags: probability, dice

I am currently using Richard Hamming's art of probability book to brush some basic concepts regarding the subject.

In this book, problem 1.7-17:

> On the roll of two dice, what is probability at least one face having 4 or else the sum of the faces equals 4?

I am arriving at an answer of $7/18$ $(11/36 + 3/36 = 7/18).$

However , he mentions the answer to be $1/18.$

Is this an error or am I making a mistake in my calculation?

Comment: I think $7/18$ is correct. It seems there is a mistake in the answer. The probability that sum of faces is $4$ is itself $3/36 > 1/18$ so the given answer is clearly incorrect.

Comment: please format your question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your calculations easily readable